# Linux + how to pick the relevant VMware tools RPM in order to install vmware tools

Tags: rhel, software-installation, vmware

we have redhat version - 6 ( VM machine ) 
that run under VM vsphere client 5.5.0

we want to install the VM ware tools on the linux machine

from this site ( vmware site )

we see many RPM that belong to vmware tools

how to know which RPM need to download? , in order to perform from scratch vmware tools installation

[image]

```
 https://packages.vmware.com/tools/esx/5.0u2/rhel6/x86_64/index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

vmware-tools-core-XX.el6.x86_64 -> need dependency by example (
vmware-tools-foundation >= 0:X.X.X
vmware-tools-libraries-nox = 0:X.X.XX
vmware-tools-guestlib = 0:X.X.XX )

I would choose all vmware-tools-* package in this directory and better choose the last repository vmware for vmware_esx55 and install it (the dependancy will be find by yum with a yum localinstall if rpm or by yum install vmware-tools-* if you have add the new depot).

Best regards